# search in multiple tables with and apply conditions in all tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

i have 2 tables relation many to many between them, this relation stored in a ptivot table tables are

- cpts
- providers
- provider_cpts

i want to search in cpts with keyword in two fields and search in providers with one keyword the conditions must apply on boh tables for example i want to search for

> heart surgery

in cpts and

> oklahoma

in providers so i want to get all cpts that contain those keyword and the count of provider that related to this cpt and contain oklahoma keyword.
im using laravel 
i tried doing this

```
Cpt::where('title', 'like','%' .$keyword.'%')
                ->OrWhere('description','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
                ->whereHas('providers',function($query) use($state){
                    if(!is_null($state)){
                        $query->where('providers.state','like','%'.$state.'%')->orderBy('state')->orderBy('city');
                    }
                })
                ->with('providers','providers.oneCptPrice','prices')
                ->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to group first two where clauses together.
2. you need to set the conditions not only to the `whereHas()` function, but to the `with()` function too.
3. And you don't need to `order` the `wherehas()` function. Because you don't get the results. Instead you need to `order` the `with()` function, Because you get the results there.

```
Cpt::where(function($query) {
    $query->where('title', 'like','%' .$keyword.'%')
          ->OrWhere('description','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
})
->whereHas('providers',function($query) use($state){
    if(!is_null($state)){
        $query->where('providers.state','like','%'.$state.'%');
    }
})
->with([
    'providers' => function ($query) use ($state) {
        if(!is_null($state)){
            $query->where('providers.state','like','%'.$state.'%')
                  ->orderBy('state')->orderBy('city');
                  ->with('oneCptPrice');
        }
    },
    'price'
])
->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(50);
```